# When I put my django project on AWS ubuntu server mysqclient error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

When i push my django project on AWS ubuntu server and run, i got mysql client error
below:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb
>   module. Did you install mysqlclient?

Then i run below command but same error:

1)sudo apt update

2)sudo apt install mysql-server

3)sudo systemctl status mysql

but same error

Comment: Did you `pip3 install mysqlclient`?

Comment: yes but get E: Unable to locate package mysqlclient